# SVG links on iPhone

Tags: ios, svg, hyperlink

I'm a graphic designer and I work with vector graphic (.svg).

I have a problem with my website and SVG links. Everything work just fine in Chrome (Desktop) and on Android and Windows mobile OS. The problem is just in iOS (Safari, Chrome,...), where I can see the SVG shape but not able to click on it.

```
<g class="Facebook">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/Muhedinovic14" target="_blank">
<circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="576.691" cy="646.241" r="46.112"/>
<path fill="#1B1B1B" d="M576.689,600.129c-25.467,0-46.111,20.646-46.111,46.114c0,25.467,20.645,46.11,46.111,46.11
    s46.115-20.644,46.115-46.11C622.805,620.774,602.156,600.129,576.689,600.129z M576.689,690.432
    c-24.404,0-44.189-19.786-44.189-44.188c0-24.406,19.785-44.192,44.189-44.192c24.406,0,44.191,19.786,44.191,44.192
    C620.881,670.646,601.096,690.432,576.689,690.432z"/>
<path fill="#1B1B1B" d="M576.689,604.386c-23.117,0-41.857,18.74-41.857,41.857c0,23.118,18.74,41.858,41.857,41.858
    c0.695,0,1.375-0.072,2.061-0.105v-0.01v-8.912v-21.22h-10.455v-12.109h10.455v-8.93c0-10.362,6.334-16.008,15.582-16.008
    c4.424,0,8.23,0.331,9.338,0.478v10.83l-6.408,0.005c-5.029,0-6.008,2.388-6.008,5.895v7.73h11.994l-1.563,12.109h-10.432v21.22
    v6.356v0.015c15.926-5.926,27.293-21.214,27.293-39.202C618.547,623.126,599.807,604.386,576.689,604.386z"/>
```

CSS:
.Facebook:hover path {
  fill: #485A96;

Please visit www.vector.ba to see details.

Any kind of help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari does not yet support href for links. You need to change the attribute to xlink:href instead.